# What chart used in google analytics?

Tags: flash, charts

I really like the dashboard line chart which is used in google analytics, Which charting solution they use, is it made by google, i can't find it in google charts.

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to be a custom chart, as it doesn't reference the charts API (at least directly):

```
/analytics/static/flash/OverTimeGraphMain.swf
```

It would seem to be most likely related to the [Annotated Timeline](http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/gallery/annotatedtimeline.html)

Answer (score 0):

The source also indicated that they use SWFObject:

```
SWFObject v1.5: Flash Player detection and embed -
 http://blog.deconcept.com/swfobject/

 SWFObject is (c) 2007 Geoff Stearns and is released under the MIT License:
 http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, this can be done with annotated time line
Since, Date range selector can be turned off in ATL
Even the line thickness can also be controlled.

Answer (score 0):

its this I'm 99% sure http://teethgrinder.co.uk/open-flash-chart/gallery-data.php